# For the deep network, assuming that each batch consists of two inputs (S and I), how to calculate whether each sample Si and all I match?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

For the deep network, assuming that each batch consists of two inputs (S and I), how to calculate whether each single sample Si and all I(batch examples) match? I wrote the following program which uses tensorarray to calculate the attention of each Si on all I, S and I have tan function relationship. Ideally, each Si will pay the most attention to its corresponding I. But the end result of convergence is that Si pays the same attention to each I.Any Advice?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.ops import tensor_array_ops
import  tensorflow.contrib.layers as layers
import numpy as np

batch_szie = 64
word_len = 16
word_emb_dim = 512
feature_dim = 512



x =  tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape =[None,1024],name="S")

sentence = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape =[None,1024],name="I")

# target = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=[None,64],name = "target")
batch_size = tf.shape(sentence)[0]
labels = tf.eye(batch_size)


loss_array  = tensor_array_ops.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=64,dynamic_size=False, infer_shape=True)
attention_array  = tensor_array_ops.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=64,dynamic_size=False, infer_shape=True)

x_pre = layers.fully_connected(
        x,
        num_outputs=1024,
        # activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
        scope="pre",
        reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)
sentence_tp = layers.fully_connected(
        sentence,
        num_outputs=1024,
        # activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
        scope="s_pre",
        reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)
def body(i,loss_array,attention_array):
    res = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(x_pre[i],1),0)       [batch_size,1,1])
    res = tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims(sentence_tp,1),res)
    res = tf.reshape(res, [batch_size])
    attention = tf.reduce_sum(labels[i] * tf.nn.softmax(res, 0), 0)
    tp_loss  = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=labels[i], logits=res))
    loss_array =loss_array.write(i,tp_loss)
    attention_array = attention_array.write(i,attention)
    return i+1 , loss_array , attention_array

_, loss_res,attention_res = tf.while_loop(cond=lambda i, _1,_2: i < 64,
                         body=body,
                         loop_vars=[tf.constant(0), loss_array,attention_array])

loss= tf.reduce_mean(loss_res.stack())
attention_all = attention_res.stack()

vars =  tf.trainable_variables()

dis_optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001, beta1=0.5, beta2=0.9)
dis_grads = tf.gradients(loss, vars)
dis_grads_and_vars = list(zip(dis_grads, vars))

for grad, var in dis_grads_and_vars:
  print("var:", var, "   ", grad)
dis_train_op =dis_optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars=dis_grads_and_vars)
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  for i in range(1000000):
    org = np.random.uniform(low=0.0,high=100,size = (64,1024))
    image = np.sin(org)
    s =    np.cos(org)
    feed_dict = {x:image,sentence:s}
    a,_,lr = sess.run([attention_all,dis_train_op,loss],feed_dict)
    print(lr)
    for j in range(1):
        print("attention:",a)
```

Converges when attention on each use case is 1/batch_size